# Getting error while loading beepr package

Tags: r

```
library(beepr)
```

> Error in get(method, envir = home) : 
>     cannot open file 'C:/Users/Amrish.kaushik/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/audio/R/audio.rdb': No such file or directory
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘beepr’

Comment: Please provide some more information about what you're doing to get this error message.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
install.packages("beepr")
library(beepr)
```